# preserving resolution when printing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am trying to print a TForm (experimenting with replacing a reporting tool). Right now I get the bitmap from the TForm then send it to the printer with the TJvPrint component.

Everything seems to work but the bar codes loose enough resolution that they are no longer able to be recognized by the scanner.

Is there a better way to preserve resolution with the TJvPrint component?
Here is what my code looks like now.

```
procedure TForm1.mniJVCPrint1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bm : TBitmap;
begin
  bm := Form1.GetFormImage;

  jvprnt1 := TJvPrint.Create(Form1);
  jvprnt1.PrintImage(bm, bsStretched ); //this prints a bitmap
  jvprnt1.Free;
  bm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect good-looking results from *any* solution where one of the steps involved a *bitmap image* of a *window*. I certainly wouldn't expect it to look better than an actual reporting tool. I think you're going down the wrong path with this experiment of yours.

Comment: @RobKennedy Any suggestions other than a bitmap? I'm willing to hear any of them.

Comment: I agree with @Rob. Reporting tools have spent literally thousands of man-hours developing code that does this for you, and reinventing the wheel needlessly just seems like a horrific waste of time and effort for what is almost certainly going to be lower-quality results. My suggestion: Stop what you're doing, and spend the time more productively elsewhere.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could take whatever code you're using to draw your bar code on your form's canvas and draw it on the printer's canvas instead. I assume you're using functions like `MoveTo` and `LineTo`. Scale your coordinates according to the relative resolutions of the screen and the printer.

Comment: To preserve resolution, do not stretch the image.

Comment: As Sertac says, you need to ask yourself why you opted for `bsStretched`. What was the reasoning behind that?

Comment: Not a direct answer: but learn how to use a TMetafile.

Comment: @Pieter For a raster image? I don't think so.

Comment: OK, I think I'll close this question and move on. Do I delete the question, leave it hanging for someone to stumble on in the future? What's the norm in this situation?